# Ninject: Provide an un-opened SqlConnection when asked for DbConnection

Tags: mapping, database-connection, ninject, sql-server-2008-express

I want to map `DbConnection` to an un-opened `SqlConnection` using `Ninject`. This is what I've done:

```
string constr = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=True; Database=TestDB";

Bind<DbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>()
    .Using<OnePerRequestBehavior>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", constr);
```

However, when trying to use the db I get an error saying that

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

(The same operation works if I just provide the connection with `new SqlConnection(constr)`...)

It turns out **the `QueryString` property of the `SqlConnection` I was given by Ninject is empty**. What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I have now tested with `kernel.Get<DbConnection>()` directly after the binding, and with the above code it still gives me an empty connection string. The following works, although it is more verbose than I want it:

```
Bind<DbConnection>().ToMethod<SqlConnection>(ctx => GetConnection());

private SqlConnection GetConnection()
{ return new SqlConnection(constr); }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

This is my entire module:

```
public class MsSqlModule : StandardModule
{
    private string constr = @"Server=AASLOEG\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=True; Database=Booking_Test";// System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mssql"].ConnectionString;

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", constr);
        var test = Kernel.Get<DbConnection>();
        test.Dispose();
    }
}
```

With a breakpoint on `var test = Kernel.Get<DbConnection>();` and stepping over, I see that `test` is populated with an `SqlConnection`, but the `ConnectionString` property is empty.

Comment: You dont mean `**Query**String` do you?

Comment: Is this the only `Bind` call you have? don't see how `Get<DBConnection>()` could fail to pass the arg [and select the non-default overload of the ctor] if it is.

Comment: You sure `constr` is initialised at the point you `Bind` ?

Comment: @Ruben, please see my update. And no, it's not a querystring ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a custom provider, and binding to it. (I've also upgraded to Ninject 2.0, which might affect the results...)

```
public class MsSqlConnectionProvider : DbConnectionProvider<SqlConnection>
{
    public string ConnectionString { get { return TestConnectionString; } }
    public string ConnectionStringFromConfigFile { get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mssql"].ConnectionString; } }
    public string TestConnectionString { get { return @"Server=AASLOEG\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=True; Database=Booking_Test"; } }

    protected override SqlConnection CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
}

public class MsSqlModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbConnection>().ToProvider<MsSqlConnectionProvider>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have seems fine, and Ninject should either use the binding or comnplain loudly iff you ask for a `DBConnection`.

Are you sure that `ImplicitSelfBinding` isnt stepping in ? Can you turn it off in yout `Module`? (But you'd need to be injecting a `SqlConnection` for that to happen).

What happens if you do a `Get<DBConnection>()` immediately after your `Bind` line?

Comment: I've updated my question with the results. How do I control ImplicitSelfBinding? (But no, I'm injecting `DbConnection`...)

Comment: ImplicitSelfBindingDefault is passed into the Module (or is it Kernel or both?) construction. You can see what the state is by looking at the ImplicitSelfBinding prop of a Module. It only means that class X gets bound to X. (i.e., it probably has nothing to do with your case - if it was on and you had no Bindings then Ninject would allow you to Get a SqlConnection and it would be default constructed. If you're definitely resolving a DBConnection, it's not going to jump in and supply a default-constructed SqlConnection behind your back or anything crazy)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but....

Found this on the [following](http://jayhollingum.blogspot.com/2011/03/ef-codefirst-databasesetinitializser.html) blog.

Just add:

> Persist Security Info=True

...to your connection string. Worked for me.